# Angular Material Table dataSource won't accept Observable from the app.service.ts

Tags: angular, angular-material, datasource, angular-material-table

I am building a simple webshop app in Angular and I want to represent products I get thru the service in an Angular Material Table.
I have a Product interface:

```
export interface Product {
    id: number;
    name: String;
    price: number;
}
```

I have a products.json in my assets folder.
In my service class have getProducts() method that reaches back to the json (in the future possibly to a more distant backend):

```
private products_url = "/assets/data/products.json";

  public getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    //return this.http.get<Product[]>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/product/all`);
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.products_url);
  }
```

In my component class I have a getProducts() function that reaches out to the service:

```
  public getProducts(): void {
    this.canteenService.getProducts().subscribe(
      (response: Product[]) => {
        this.products = response;
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    )
  }
```

When I want to declare the dataSource for the Material Table in a way that it gets the products thru this getProducts() function in the component, I get an error.

```
  public dataToDisplay = this.getProducts();;
  public dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.dataToDisplay);
```

The error says: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Product[]'.ts(2345)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how an Observable works. An Observable is asynchronous. So you don't get the response else inside subscribe function. So you need

```
dataSource:MatDataSource<any> //outside you declare the variable

public getProducts(): void {
    this.canteenService.getProducts().subscribe(
      (response: Product[]) => {
        this.products = response;
        //here asign the matDataSource
        this.dataSource = new MatDataSource(this.dataToDisplay);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    )
  }
```

BTW, if you don't need sort or paginate, the data source of a mat-table can be an array, so you can use [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

```
dataSource$=this.canteenService.getProducts() //<--see that is an observable

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource$ |async">
   ...
</table>
```

NOTE: By defect all the variables of a component you declare are public, so it's unnecessary use `public variable:any` -you can declare as `variable:any`-

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getProducts()` from your component doesn't return anything, you even set the return type as `void`, also, the naming convention for this particular function is wrong since you are not `get`ting anything

I suggest you do the following:

```js
getProducts$(): Observable<Product[]> {
  return this.canteenService.getProducts();
}
```

```html
<table [dataSource]="getProducts$()">
 <...>
</table>
```