# Angular 16 Material Table dataSource doesn't accept declarative RxJS Object[]

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material, rxjs6

**Issue**: Angular/Material Table doesn't like my dataSource and throws this error:

**error TS2322: Type 'ReturnedDataList[] | null' is not assignable to type 'CdkTableDataSourceInput<ReturnedDataList.>'.**

I am retrieving data from a backend service with declarative RxJS that I am trying to use as the datasource for my Material Table.

Please **ignore** variable names as I had to change them for this post.

We grab the data and map it down to an Object Array like so:

```
handleData$ = this.dataService.retrieveData$
    .pipe(
      map(dataList=> dataList.fakeObject.baseFakeObject?.returnedDataList?? [])
    );
```

So now `handleData$` is of type Observable<ReturnedDataList[]>

Then, we pass that through as an `@Input` to our `table.component.ts` like so:

`home.component.html`

```
<app-table [dataSource$]="handleData$"></app-table>
```

and in our `table.component.ts` we have this:

```
@Input()
  dataSource$: Observable<ReturnedDataList[]>;
```

The data is all retrieved fine, but when I try to add it to our Material Table DataSource Like so:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource$ | async">
```

I get this error during compile time:
**error TS2322: Type 'ReturnedDataList[] | null' is not assignable to type 'CdkTableDataSourceInput'.**

This is my first time working with a material table.

I've found this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73978847/angular-material-table-datasource-wont-accept-observable-from-the-app-service-t) but for some reason it's not working to try to do it async?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried `?` operator on html template side in your case (` <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource$ | async">`)? Angular renders the view before `dataSource` got a value assigned, it causes an exception. `?.` stops evaluating if `dataSource` is null or undefined, which usually happens when data is fetched async.

Comment: Did you try `(dataSource$ | async) || []`?

Comment: I'm going to try both of your solutions

Comment: @JulianLin can you explain to me why that works?

Comment: @DonaldGroezinger, dataSource should be or an Array or a MatTableDataSource, using `[dataSource]="(whatever || [])"` you be sure that if whatever is null or undefined the dataSource will be an array (really an empty array) if it's not null or undefined gets the value or whatever

Comment: @Eliseo okay so that's why it works. Is there a way I can reference my data like in a standard async pipe where it's normally ```dataSource$ | async as items```, and then I could use items wherever, but I can't with this? I'm asking because our rows have checkboxes, and so if my dataSource only returns a list with a length of 1, (so 1 row in the table) I want it to autoselect without clicking? Any thoughts to that?

Comment: @DonaldGroezinger, I imagine:`((dataSource$ | async) || []) as items,`

Comment: Thank you all for the tremendous help. I struggle a bit with angular material table and how it handles the data so thank you!

Comment: @Eliseo that did not work. I appreciate the help though.